# how to use loops in a javascript quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I was able to create a quiz using javascript and html. It is a simple quiz with 5 questions, for now only the solution for question one appears when the user is wrong, I tried adding a function  for the other questions but it wont run, I want to find out how do i loop through all the five question to give solution at the bottom of every wrong answer given by the user.

```html
<HEAD>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->

 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .visible {
  display: block;
 }
 
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">


// Insert scooter questions number of questions
var numQues = 5;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(5);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.";
answers[1] = "Road which cross.";
answers[2] = "When a traffic officer order you to do so.";
answers[3] = "Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.";
answers[4] = "(i), (ii) and (iii)";
answers[5] = "A marked pedestrian crossing ahead.";


function getScore(form) {
 showCorrectAnswers();

  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;
  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
  break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";
  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}

function showCorrectAnswers() {
 var q1Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.q1-inputs input');
 var correctAnswer = document.querySelector('.q1-inputs span');
 var correct = correctAnswer.textContent;
 q1Inputs.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
   if (element.value !== correct) {
    correctAnswer.classList.remove('hidden');
   } else {
    correctAnswer.classList.add('hidden');
   }
  }
 });
}

//  End -->
</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<h3>Scooter quiz by johnson</h3>

<form name="quiz">




1. Which rule is considered the most important RULE OF THE ROAD in South Africa?
<ul class="q1-inputs" style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.">Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Do not exceed the speed limit.">Do not exceed the speed limit.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</li>
  <span class="hidden" style="color:red;">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</span>
  
   
</ul>




2. Sign L9 warns you about... ahead.

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Where you are also not allowed to park."> Where you are also not allowed to park..</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>



3.Under what circumstances, if any, are you allowed to drive your motor motor vehicle on the right-hand side of a public road with traffic moving in both directions?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.">When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When a traffic officer order you to do so.">When a traffic officer order you to do so.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Under no circumstance.">Under no circumstance.</li>
</ul>



4.Sign CC9 is found at ..
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.">Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.">Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Sharp curve to the right.">Sharp curve to the right.</li>
</ul>

5.You may not obtain a learner’s license if...

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A first-aid post."> A first-aid post.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>








<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="100" disabled>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript update

```
var getScoreButton = document.getElementById("getScore"),
quizSections = document.getElementById("quizForm").querySelectorAll("ul"),
quizScore = document.getElementById("percentage"),
quizSolutions = document.getElementById("solutions"),
answers = new Array(5),
score = 0,
solutions = '';

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.";
answers[1] = "Road which cross.";
answers[2] = "When a traffic officer order you to do so.";
answers[3] = "Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.";
answers[4] = "(i), (ii) and (iii)";
answers[5] = "A marked pedestrian crossing ahead.";

function checkAnswers(source) {

    source.forEach(function(section, index){

        var selectedAnswer = section.querySelector("input:checked");

        if(selectedAnswer){

            if(answers[index] === selectedAnswer.value){

                score+=1;
            }else{

                solutions+= (index+1) + '. ' + answers[index] + "\n";
            }
        }else{
            solutions+= (index+1) + '. ' + answers[index] + "\n";
        }
    });

    quizScore.value = score;
    quizSolutions.value = solutions;

    score = 0;
    solutions = '';
}


getScoreButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

    checkAnswers(quizSections);
});
```

HTML update (added some id's)

`<input type="button" value="Get score" id="getScore">
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage" id="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" id="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="100" disabled>`

Comment: at lucian i should replace my whole js with your updated js?

Comment: can you put a code snipet so i can run it from this website

Comment: yes, replace your js code with that piece. Also replace the piece of html

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Also add the id of `quizForm` to your form :)  `<form name="quiz" id="quizForm">`

Answer (score -3):

You can use .getAttribute('value') instesd of .value

**UPDATE**

```
function showCorrectAnswers() {
 var x = ['q1-inputs', 'q2-inputs','q3-inputs', 'q4-inputs', 'q5-inputs'];
 for(value of x){
  var q1Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.'+value+' input');
  var correctAnswer = document.querySelector('.'+value+' span');
  var correct = correctAnswer.textContent;
  q1Inputs.forEach(function(element) {

   if (element.checked) {
    if (element.getAttribute('value') !== correct) {
     correctAnswer.classList.remove('hidden');
   } else {
     correctAnswer.classList.add('hidden');
   }
  }});
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. As far as I can tell, all you've done is change the indentation of the original code and markup.

Comment: I have used getAttribute('value')  where as in the give code it was .value which was giving an error to user

Comment: Then say as much. You've presented your answer in an almost impossible to consume format. Nobody is interested in reading your entire blob of code to spot the differences.

Comment: Sorry it was my fault as it was my first answer so I was not aware of such things.

Comment: but when i run code,it does not do what i show the correct answers bellow the wrong solutions presented by the user

Comment: there is no textarea or an input with name solutions in code. So can you please add it so that it can show correct answers in that area

Comment: @rohit180 i want the correct answer to appear bellow the incorrectly answered question. the correct answer for question 1 is a, if you select b or c the correct answer appears in red (i used span for that), what i want to do that for all questions using a loop